Introduce a view modifier that is based on properties set by protocols in SwiftUI
I am currently trying to set up a convenience architecture for our view redaction. I therefore added protocols that constrain View and ViewModel to certain properties. I then want to implement a view modifier that makes use of these properties.
Let's assume we have the following setup:
protocol ViewModelDriven {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}

protocol RedactionProviding {
    var isRedacted: Bool { get }
}

extension View where Self: ViewModelDriven, ViewModel: RedactionProviding {
    func redact() -> some View {
        redacted(reason: viewModel.isRedacted ? .placeholder : [])
    }
}

Up to that everything works fine. The modifier uses viewModel and isRedacted provided by the protocols.
When I now try to implement a View/ViewModel using this setup, I get the following error when using the modifier: Referencing instance method 'redact()' on 'View' requires that 'some View' conform to 'ViewModelDriven'
struct FooView: View, ViewModelDriven {
    typealias ViewModel = FooViewModel
    var viewModel: FooViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
            .redact()
    }
}

class FooViewModel: RedactionProviding {
    var isRedacted: Bool { true }
}

As far as I understand, this is due to the modifier being attached to an opaque some View.
Does anybody know if and how I can work around that? Is it even intended to do things like that with SwiftUI or am I on the wrong path? Any help appreciated!

Empty view doesn’t conform to your protocols or some View for that matter. This approach will be a nightmare to scale.

Indeed - that's why I try to add the modifier to the View protocol instead of each of its implementations. Isn't there a way of doing so?

No because the parent conforms not the children. In a very unscalable way you can make every possible child conform too. You can also use a closure instead of a modifier, a closure that is available at the parent label to be used on children.

I think your intention is something more like this
extension ViewModelDriven where ViewModel : RedactionProviding {
    @ViewBuilder func redact<Content>(content: () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View {
        switch viewModel.isRedacted {
        case true:
            Text("Placeholder")
        case false:
            content()
        }
    }
}

that way redact is available within FooView and not on the complex views that make up the body.
You can then use it
struct FooView: View, ViewModelDriven {
    typealias ViewModel = FooViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        redact {
            Text("Hello World!!")
        }
    }
}

Here is a full example
struct FooView: View, ViewModelDriven {
    typealias ViewModel = FooViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        redact {
            Text("Hello World!!")
        }
    }
}

class FooViewModel: RedactionProviding {
    var isRedacted: Bool { true }
}
@MainActor
protocol ViewModelDriven {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}

protocol RedactionProviding {
    var isRedacted: Bool { get }
}

extension ViewModelDriven where ViewModel : RedactionProviding {
    @ViewBuilder func redact<Content>(content: () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View {
        switch viewModel.isRedacted {
        case true:
            Text("Placeholder")
        case false:
            content()
        }
    }
}

Note that "ViewModelDriven" will present many more challenges with SwiftUI, this is just a means to answer your question and shouldn't be used as an example of efficiency.

Thanks for your effort, this works! It seems that the concept I thrived for is not the right one for this use case though - I'll just get rid of the protocols :)
